# Java web framework coming from Django

Tags: java, django, web-frameworks

I've worked on a lot of web applications in Django. Now I've to write a webapp in Java as the system it will be interfacing with is all written in Java.

I'm not sure what would be a good framework to work with. I've a lot of experience working in Java, so language is not a problem but I'm looking for a framework that favors conventions over configuration and is easy to get started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/), it's inspired by Ruby on Rails and has a very short development cycle - just save your source code and update your browser. It also has good integration with testing frameworks. I have used it for a few months and it is easy to understand.

Comment: coming from django, choosing play framework is really a no brainer, you will feel right at home

Answer (score 2):

["Running Django on Jython"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/)

Comment: it would be nice to give a bit more details on this... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers